# Como encriptar várias variáveis dentro de um arquivo com php?

Tags: php, regex, foreach, aes, replace

Estou usando o php para ler um arquivo para uma `$string`, ele possui algumas *palavras* variáveis que preciso encontrar e substituir por outras, ou seja, preciso obter essas variáveis, encripta-las com AES e escrever novamente onde elas estavam, fazendo um `replace`.

As variáveis *não tem o mesmo nome*, e veem depois do parâmetro `cmd=`, a quantidade delas pode variar.

Exemplo de arquivo com as variáveis:

```
Inicio
texto=nome?cmd=0a7-5.ext
data...
texto=nome?cmd=12345.ext
data...
texto=nome?cmd=abcd.ext
```

O valor a ser substituído é a própria variável encriptada com o seguinte AES:

```
//fnEncrypt("0a7-5", "1234567890123456");
function fnEncrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
    return rtrim(
        base64_encode(
            mcrypt_encrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                $sSecretKey, $sValue, 
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 
                mcrypt_create_iv(
                    mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
                        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                    ), 
                    MCRYPT_RAND)
                )
            ), "\0"
        );
}
```

O que é esperado:

```
Inicio
texto=nome?cmd=dxZIKbLDEtI/m81cEGnB+dVbmy1C+fcIxmeBGHpyYY0=
data...
texto=nome?cmd=+FFzyIqAENF13PnEj5XqpHYlMD2u08uHmWK7HYDyPos=
data...
texto=nome?cmd=cTySfjmfN85GgcWS3aVHSwExC2ZBldBqh9xJq9ndAmc=
```

Como eu poderia substituir essas variáveis por sua versão criptografada com AES, sabendo que a quantidade delas e seus valores são diferentes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumindo que sempre começa com `"?cmd="` e terminando no final da linha, pode usar

> [**preg_replace_callback($regex, $callback, $string)**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace-callback.php)
>
> O callback que será chamado e passado um array dos elementos combinados na string

Expressão regular:

```regex
/(\?cmd=)(.+)/
```

Código:

```
function fnEncrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey)
{
    return rtrim(
        base64_encode(
            mcrypt_encrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                $sSecretKey, $sValue, 
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 
                mcrypt_create_iv(
                    mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
                        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                    ), 
                    MCRYPT_RAND)
                )
            ), "\0"
        );
}

$string = "
Inicio
texto=nome?cmd=0a7-5.ext
data...
texto=nome?cmd=12345.ext
data...
texto=nome?cmd=abcd.ext
";

function fnEncrypt_match($matches) {
    return $matches[1] . fnEncrypt($matches[2], "1234567890123456");
}

$stringAES = preg_replace_callback('/(\?cmd=)(.+)/', 'fnEncrypt_match', $string);

echo "<pre>
        $stringAES
      </pre>";
```

Resultado:

```
Inicio
texto=nome?cmd=dxZIKbLDEtI/m81cEGnB+dVbmy1C+fcIxmeBGHpyYY0=
data...
texto=nome?cmd=+FFzyIqAENF13PnEj5XqpHYlMD2u08uHmWK7HYDyPos=
data...
texto=nome?cmd=cTySfjmfN85GgcWS3aVHSwExC2ZBldBqh9xJq9ndAmc=
```

---

> **Atenção:** o código usado para encriptar não é totalmente seguro.
>   É recomendável usar [**libsodium**](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php).
>
> Mais informação: *[PHP AES encrypt / decrypt [image: EN]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30166085/5290909)*

Comment: Quando tiver um tempinho dou uma testada, agradeço a informação sobre o código AES, ele serviu mais como exemplo e para minhas tentativas, uma substituição por uma versão segura seria fácil, também recomendo que não usem esse código inseguro, a não ser para fins didáticos, ou por sua própria conta em risco.